How can I add custom packages to a SUSE automated installation using AutoYaST?
I am trying to add custom packages to an installation of SUSE 15 that is performed via AutoYaST and an installation USB, and I found this section in their documentation (section 4.9.3), but I am not understanding very well the steps to follow to get it.
They mention the use of the command create_package_descr; what I did was to copy the rpm I want to add to the Module-Basesystem/x86_64/ folder in my USB and run the previous command there. But then I am lost in the steps to add the package in my AutoYaST file so it can be installed among the others.
I tried to add them in this part of the code:
    <packages t="list">
      ...
      <package>alacritty</package>
      ...
    </packages>

but when running the AutoYaST process I get the error that the package was not found.
What should I do?

Is this a package that is in the SUSE repo or a custom rpm you want to install? If a custom package you need to do this in the  section, you essentially create a script, telling it the location of the rpm and then rpm -ivh the file so something like this
...
<!-- Post-Installation Scripts -->
<scripts>
  <chroot-scripts config:type="list">
    <script>
      <filename>install_custom_package.sh</filename>
      <source>
        <![CDATA[
#!/bin/bash
# Path to the RPM file (assuming it is copied to /tmp during installation)
RPM_FILE="/tmp/custom-package.rpm"

# Install the custom RPM package
if [ -f $RPM_FILE ]; then
    rpm -ivh $RPM_FILE
else
    echo "Custom RPM file not found: $RPM_FILE"
fi

...
The ... is for packages within the SUSE repos or "modules / extensions"
